# How to use svcutil to generate client proxies for 2 separate services?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm running 2 WCF services on the same host: one HTTP (unsecured) and one Net.Tcp (secured), off different port numbers.  The same client needs to call both services.  How do you run svcutil to generate the correct proxy files & app.config, including both services?

Comment: Are they both the same service, or two different services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'oh!  It's as simple as this:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:GeneratedProxy.cs /config:app.config net.tcp://localhost:8000/ http://localhost:8005
```

IOW, just list your services one after the other...